# Integrating stripe connect using javascript

Tags: ajax, oauth-2.0, payment, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate stripe connect in my application here is reference url (https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth). Here they have specified to post authorization code after user have created account

**curl -X POST https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token \
  -d client_secret=sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2 \
  -d code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE \
  -d grant_type=authorization_code**

here i have client secret and authorization code but when i do ajax post like below

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType:"json",
      url: "https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token/",
      data: {client_secret:"sk_test_gcpX7F3XXXXXXXXXXXX",code:"ac_43xnkqCpBtNu6ywXXXXXXXXXXX",grant_type:"ac_43xnkqCpBtNu6ywqLXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"},
      success: function(resp) {
        alert(resp);
      }
});
```

I am getting error like 301 moved permanently, Even I don't now can i do ajax post or is there any way we can do this instead of js

can any one help me in getting user account details using accesstoken.

Answer (score 0):

First, your request is wrong and you should have

```
grant_type : "authorization_code"
```

and not with the auth code you just got from the authorization callbak. The other params are fine.

Although I tried using JS instead of JAVA and I got a CORS error at first, so I then I used

```
dataType : "jsonp"
```

But the Stripe's server return a response in HTML format and I got a MiME error.
I finally gave up on doing it with javascript and did it from my Backend. Seems like a safer option anyway :)

Strip advise you to use a [oAuth2 client library](http://oauth.net/2/) to handle the token generation.
It now depends the language your backend is using.

Good Luck !